# Add product to cart from email link

Tags: email, addtocart, magento-1.6

I am running a promotion and would like to make it very easy for customers to add three items to their shopping carts.

The research I have done around URL querystrings no longer seems to work on Magento 1.6.2, due to a requirement of a form key value.

Is there any way for me to be able to add one of each of 3 simple products to a customers basket from a link in an email?

Not scamming etc, just want to make life easy for people interested in buying the special offer product(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the easy way to do this (Tested in Magento `1.6.2` only) is to simply get the ID from Magento admin of the product you want to link to, and then construct the URL as follows:

http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=12345&qty=1

www.example.com is your website, and the "/checkout" part will change if your Magento installation is not in the root of your domain. So, if your Magento store is installed into a subfolder called store, your link would be:

http://www.example.com/store/checkout/cart/add?product=12345&qty=1

`product=12345` is the ID of the product to add to the cart.

`qty=1` is the quantity to add to the cart.

This will work for simple products (products that do not have any options required before adding to cart).

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This method is no longer valid since Magento 1.7 as you now require a formKey to add to cart.

Comment: Actually formKeys were added in Magento 1.8

Answer (score 5):

You should create your own module for this with the product sku/id as a parameter.
Code might look something like this:

```
$id = '100'; // Get the id  with $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')
$qty = '2'; // Replace qty with your qty
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

After that you can do a redirect to the cart or to the homepage.

The link in your email will be something like http://domain.com/router/controller/action/id/product-id

Some more info [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programatically-add-bundle-product-to-cart-n-magento/).